Confusion about MPPI Path Angle Critic
Required Info:
Branch: main
Commit: 5a8cbd3
Description:
We are considering use of the PathAngleCritic to align the angle of the robot with the orientation information produced by kinematically feasible planners. Our understanding is that mode 2 in the PathAngleCritic is suited for this purpose, but there is some confusion about the intent and implementation:

Is the intended outcome of using the PathAngleCritic in mode 2 that the robot heading aligns with the orientation of the lookahead point or that the robot direction of movement aligns with the orientation of the lookahead point?
Based on PathAngleCritic code, lines 138-152, higher penalties occur when the trajectories' yaws do not align with the direction of travel (calculated using an arctan between the goal position and each trajectory position). The goal_yaw is only used to determine whether or not to normalize yaws_between_points; therefore, the cost is not associated with the goal_yaw. If this is correct, how does mode 2 of the PathAngleCritic work wrt its stated purpose?


what is the meaning of the required info section

The required info part of the navigation2 github issue format, and the question was copied here without reformatting.

Its worth quickly highlighting the intent of the PathAngle. We have 3 path tracking critics that together give us really nice path tracking behavior that's able to deviate from the path if more optimal by other objective functions (or not, depending on how you tune):

Path Align --> Does the main alignment against the path to give you path tracking acccuracy
Path Following --> Drives the robot to make progress along the direction of the path
Path Angle --> The most subtle of them, is used when there is a large angle between the robot's heading and the immediate future of the path. In most iterations, it doesn't contribute anything to the scoring except when in sharp turns or a replan asks the robot to turn around. The other critics will eventually make the robot adjust or turn around, but will take longer and less clean. This makes it more reactive and 'steers the ship' back on the general course.

With that in mind, the path angle is only offering a score when we have a large angular distance.

The different modes are for different plan inputs and behavior desires:

FORWARD_PREFERENCE --> We generally prefer to move forward (normal robots)
NO_DIRECTIONAL_PREFERENCE --> We don't care if we move forward or backward, genuinely a bidirectional platform (not many robots, but happens sometimes with completely symmetric sensor coverage - no real 'front' or 'back')
CONSIDER_FEASIBLE_PATH_ORIENTATIONS --> When you have a path that contains your orientation information about your desired orientation, use those

So, if using the feasible path orientations mode, it will score the "I need to turn around / correct my orientation course imminently" based on the orientations embedded in the path from the output of a feasible planner. This is opposed to the other 2 which will imply a desire to move forward (so any path points behind will be scored harshly) or bidirectional desire (so path points mirrored behind are OK since backward is equally valid).

Thanks for bringing clarity to the nuances between critics. However, the implementation for PathAngleCritic mode 2 is still not clear to me. (1) How does the critic penalize trajectories that do not respect the path orientation when goal_yaw is not a part of the cost function? (2) Why does goal_yaw determine whether or not to normalize yaws_between_points? It seems to me that mode 1 says "if the robot is trying to go backwards, flip the angle to allow that," while mode 2 compares a direction of movement (yaws_between_points) and a heading (goal_yaw) then stops considering goal_yaw in the cost.
